# ioredis - ClusterAllFailedError: Failed to refresh slots cache issue with Redis Cluster to Connect with AWS MemoryDb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, bullmq, amazon-memory-db

i am use redis cluster connect with memoryDB aws

```
const connection = new Redis.Cluster(
  [{ host: "clustercfg.jb-bot-dev-memorydb.czxa87.memorydb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com", port: 6379}],
  {
    redisOptions: {
      password: "memorydb@12345678"
    },
  }
);

connection.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Redis Client Ready");
});
connection.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("Redis Client Connected");
});
connection.on("error", (error) => {
  console.log("Redis Client Connection Error", error);
});
```

error:
`ClusterAllFailedError: Failed to refresh slots cache. at tryNode (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/cluster/index.js:308:31) at /usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/cluster/index.js:325:21 at Timeout.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/cluster/index.js:662:24) at Timeout.run (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/utils/index.js:117:22) at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:559:11) at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) { lastNodeError: Error: timeout at timeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/utils/index.js:120:38) at EventEmitter.getInfoFromNode (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/cluster/index.js:659:67) at tryNode (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/cluster/index.js:314:19) at EventEmitter.refreshSlotsCache (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/cluster/index.js:333:9) at /usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/cluster/index.js:167:22 }`

connect redis with memoryDB of aws